# How to get event when clicking on selected item in JqueryUI Selectmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code:

```
$( "#software" ).on( "selectmenuchange" , function ( e, ui ) {
        // do some stuff
});
```

When clicking on the already selected item, nothing happens because it doesn't change. How can I conver this case too?

Comment: Please provide your HTML so we can try and debug it, preferably in a jsfiddle.

Comment: @UncleRico How to add jquery and jqueryui to jsfiddle?

Comment: you can add them as 'external resources' on the left hand side, or as a framework or extension under the Javascript menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( ".selector" ).selectmenu({
  open: function( event, ui ) {
    //on open event
  },
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    //on select event
  }
});
```